# how to chose fieldType filters (for example in german)

Tags: solr

I indexed data in German language, but the results are not so good, so I'm trying to find a way and improve the searches.

The schema is very simple:

```
<fields>
           <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
           <field name="title" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
           <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        </fields>
```

The title is configured by this:

```
<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- less aggressive: <filter class="solr.GermanMinimalStemFilterFactory"/> -->
        <!-- more aggressive: <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2"/> -->
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

How can I decide which improvements to make, if I should choose the "less aggressive" or the "more aggressive" filter instead of GermanLightStemFilterFactory or not?

can I make AB testing during the queries? for one query to tell solr to use GermanMinimalStemFilterFactory and for another query to use SnowballPorterFilterFactory?
And this way I'll be able to know which stemming is performing better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what do you mean by *the results are not good*. Are you not finding what you are looking for? Is the sorting/ranking wrong? There are several ways to tweak this.

Since you are mentioning your schema and configuration, I assume words do not match the way you want them to match.

### Finding the right type to start with

I usually set up several types at once with slightly different configurations and use the **Analyses** Tab in Solr Admin (`http://localhost:8080/solr/#/CORE/analysis`). Then I make a list of some typical sentences and queries and try them out with the different types just to see what happens and how they match. 
If you already have an application it is even easier. Find popular queries from your log and important or popular titles. For me, most of the time the 'medium' and more agressive stemmer give very similar results. But the light stemmer can make a big difference. If you are matching long, natural text, a strong stemmer is usually a good fit, if you are matching specific names or products, light stemming gives better results.

### Other Filters

Stemming is not the only thing that is important with your schema. You seem to have the default stopword list in place. Make sure to tweak that list. Less stopwords in your index mean better scoring. Go to **Schema Browser** in Solr Admin and select your title field. Load the top 100 term infos. If there are any meaningless words in there, add those words to your stop word list (requires reindexing). Also check for other things like numbers. This might be an indication that your Tokenizer needs to be tweaked and kill those (unless, of corse, they are important to you, but for me, single digit numbers usually add no value).

### A/B Testing

If you really only have one field (I usually have more than one), copying the data from one field into an other with a different type is a good and easy way to start. But the A/B testing still has to happen within your application. You need to send, say, 10% of your queries to that other field and monitor conversion (items liked, products bought or however you measure success).

If your schema gets more complex, use two cores. I always have my selected core (the one that is live) and a candiate core (the one that is challenging the live core). This strategy requires to index your data twice (send your data to core1 and core2), once for each core. But it allows you to test more than just the field types, you can play with different scoring etc. as well. Again, you will need to find a way to track how success full your candidate core is.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform AB testing by creating multiple fields with differing underlying fieldTypes in your index that implement the respective FilterFactories that you want to test out. You can leverage the solr [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) directive to copy your `title` field into your different fields for testing.

Comment: ok, will try that now. any other configurations that i should try and change except the stemming filters?